# SforceService is not generated in Visual Studio

Tags: api, integration, wsdl

I was following these steps:
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Integrating_Force.com_with_Microsoft_.NET

I downloaded the enterprise wsdl and added the service reference. When I try to access the SforceService it does not exist.

I am using VS 2013. Has anyone else gotten this to work?

Answer (score 4):

Mentioning below step by step guide with screen shots to connect .NET console application with Salesforce.

[https://cloudvista.wordpress.com/2015/07/21/connecting-net-console-application-to-salesforce-via-enterprise-wsdl/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GkMQ.jpg)

Generally the issue is in adding service reference.It you're unsure, try deleting the reference and adding it again.
If it is added succesfully, you'll get screen like this: 
[image]

Also note while adding reference, you've to follow path like this in Visual Studio :

Project Name | Right click 'Add' | Service referece | Advanced | Add Web Reference 
This will land you screen like above screen shot.

Revert in case of any further doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are if you use the stock Enterprise WSDL using a web reference or service reference from Visual Studio you will encounter a .NET XmlSerializer issue related to the unbounded ListViewRecord element.

I've written about it with respect to the Partner API in [Importing the Salesforce Winter 15 Partner API to .NET](http://www.fishofprey.com/2014/10/importing-salesforce-winter-15-partner.html). There is also a specific Knowledge Article about the same problem - ["Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1)" is returned when .Net integration tries to parse the Enterprise WSDL version 32.0](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000205824&language=en_US).

Are you encountering any compile errors with the generated classes?

Answer (score 1):

You can add either a .NET 2.0 style Web reference, or a .NET 3.0 style Service reference, depending on your version of Visual Studio and preferred developer environment. A .NET 3.0 style reference uses services like SoapClient instead of SforceService.

reference : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_steps_import_wsdl.htm